# How to check if grep matched in a batch script?

Tags: bash

In a list of static archive files on Ubuntu, I need to obtain the specific archive that defines a function. Here is the script I put together:

```
for line in `find . -iname '*\.a'`; do
 nm $line 2>/dev/null | grep -H "T $1"
done
```

The problem is that `grep` is being fed the standard input. I am wondering if there is a way to check if `grep` succeeded and, if it did, display the filename. Or, may be there is a better way to achieve what I want. Regards.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for safe ways to do what you are trying to do with that `find` command loop. And check the return codes from `grep` (and the `-q` flag).

Comment: Did you tried to execute the script with `bash -x scriptname.sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Use recursive globs to find files. This avoids problems with special chars.
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for file in ./**/*.[aA]
do
  # Ignore grep output and instead check its return code
  if nm "$file" 2> /dev/null | grep -q "T $1"
  then
    echo "$file matches"
  fi
done
```

Here's an example run:

```
/home/me $ cd /usr/lib
/usr/lib $ myscript __sha512_init_ctx
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.a matches
/usr/lib $
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in `find . -iname '*\.a'`; do
  nm $line 2>/dev/null | grep -H "T $1"
  [[ $PIPESTATUS[1] -eq 0 ]] && echo $line
done
```

---

From bash's manpage:

```
PIPESTATUS
       An array variable (see Arrays below) containing a list
       of exit status values from the processes in the
       most-recently-executed foreground pipeline (which may
       contain only a single command).
```